# Создание ленточного меню на Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Как реализовать простое ленточное меню на *Windows Forms*? возможно ли вообще это без применения специальных библиотек?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартного контрола нет.

Вы можете его сделать самостоятельно, но это будет не просто. Как это вообще делать можно посмотреть в статьях по созданию пользовательских элементов управления. Например, [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/6hws6h2t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Можно воспользоваться компонентами с открытым кодом. Пример, [тут](http://officeribbon.codeplex.com/), [тут](https://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/), [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application-Cs) или [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25907/A-Professional-Ribbon-You-Will-Use-Now-with-orb).

Есть еще много платных:

- http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/ribbonbar-overview.html
- https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2524
- http://www.componentone.com/Studio/
- http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/toolbars#Overview